# How concurrency implementation in Nhibernat 3.1

Tags: nhibernate, concurrency, nhibernate-mapping, mapping

I have a project by nhibernate 3.1 .
I need to concurrency implementation in project.
I Add "Version" to hbm file :

```
 <class name="Person" table="Person_Person"  >

    <id name="Id" type="Int64" unsaved-value="0" >
      <generator class="native" />
    </id>

    <version name="Version" />   

    <property name="FirstName" column="FirstName"
       type="String(255)" update="true" insert="true" access="property" not-null="false" />

    <property name="LastName" column="LastName"
       type="String(255)" update="true" insert="true" access="property" not-null="false" />

  </class>
```

Also i add a version field to entity :

```
virtual protected int Version { get; set; }
```

Also i add a version field to DataBase by int type.

This implementation is correct only for once. 
It just works when version value in database is '0' .
After first update this row in table, this value change to '1'.
But for next update when version field is not '0' for example '1' , throw exception by this message:

```
Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect): [RCISP.Domain.Entities.Person#4]
```

What should I do?

Stack trace is :

```
   at NHibernate.Persister.Entity.AbstractEntityPersister.Update(Object id, Object[] fields, Object[] oldFields, Object rowId, Boolean[] includeProperty, Int32 j, Object oldVersion, Object obj, SqlCommandInfo sql, ISessionImplementor session)
   at NHibernate.Persister.Entity.AbstractEntityPersister.UpdateOrInsert(Object id, Object[] fields, Object[] oldFields, Object rowId, Boolean[] includeProperty, Int32 j, Object oldVersion, Object obj, SqlCommandInfo sql, ISessionImplementor session)
   at NHibernate.Persister.Entity.AbstractEntityPersister.Update(Object id, Object[] fields, Int32[] dirtyFields, Boolean hasDirtyCollection, Object[] oldFields, Object oldVersion, Object obj, Object rowId, ISessionImplementor session)
   at NHibernate.Action.EntityUpdateAction.Execute()
   at NHibernate.Engine.ActionQueue.Execute(IExecutable executable)
   at NHibernate.Engine.ActionQueue.ExecuteActions(IList list)
   at NHibernate.Engine.ActionQueue.ExecuteActions()
   at NHibernate.Event.Default.AbstractFlushingEventListener.PerformExecutions(IEventSource session)
   at NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultFlushEventListener.OnFlush(FlushEvent event)
```

Comment: Version in Person Class alone is Correct, but after relation by another class is problem. For example relation by Family class (one-to-many) . I add version field to both entity classes and both hbm files. it is correct?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you doing it right. It should work. Try following:

1. Make sure that no other session is modifying the same object
   (StaleObjectStateException that you getting might be legitimate).
2. Make sure that nothing in the database itself is updating Version column (trigger for example)
3. Make sure that nothing in your code is changing the Version property. It is for NHibernate use only.
4. Remove `unsaved-value="0"` from id mapping. See if it works after that.
5. Update your answer with a stack trace and the actual Version values in the database and in the object (right before you save the object).

Comment: I check this cases, but my problem is not resolved. does it correct that after update row, version value change to '1'? does not should  stay '0' after update row?

Comment: version value in the object is updated by nhibernate and is compared to the value in the database during update. It might be a good idea if you isolate the a problem: write a standalone app that reproduces the issue.

Comment: I do not understand
What should I do?
Please explain further

Comment: Your code seems to be correct and it works for me. Write a simple console app that uses NHibernate with one mapped class and Version. You need to isolate the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have to turn on dynamic-update to get optimistic concurrency checking to work. See [this blog entry](http://ayende.com/blog/3946/nhibernate-mapping-concurrency).

```
<class name="Person" table="Person_Person" dynamic-update="true">
```

Comment: 'Version' works as expected without 'dynamic-update' in my tests. Isn't 'dynamic-update' required only for versioning **without** version numbers or timestamps?

Comment: @Dmitry - I don't know, perhaps I'm misreading the documentation "If you enable dynamic-update, you will have a choice of optimistic locking strategies: "http://knol.google.com/k/nhibernate-chapter-5-basic-o-r-mapping#5%282E%291%282E%293%282E%29%28C2%29%28A0%29class